# Limit Printing of the prolog facts to THREE times?

Tags: prolog

Say I have 10 facts `path(X)` in the database.

How do I limit it to printing the first 3 from the database?

I have tried using recursive technique but it seems that it will only unify with the first one.

All helps appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities. Both need to utilize extra-logical properties of Prolog.

(1) You collect all facts in a list and then print the first N items of this list using recursion. This approach is clear, but it could be inefficient when there are many facts (e.g. thousands) and only few of them will be written (e.g. 3).

```
print1(N) :- 
    findall(path(X), path(X), List),
    print1(List, N).

print1([], N) :- !.
print1([H|T], N) :- 
    writeln(H),
    N1 is N - 1, N1 > 0,
    print1(T, N1).

?- print1(3).
```

(2) You can use a retractable counter and a failure driven loop. This approach is less elegant than the first one but will be more efficient in the case there are many facts and only few of them are written.

```
:- dynamic count/1.
print2(N) :-
    assert(count(N)), !,
    path(X), writeln(path(X)),
    retract(count(K)),
    K1 is K - 1,
    (K1 > 0 -> assert(count(K1)); true, !), 
    fail.

?- print2(3).
```

**Addition**: Printing first N "smallest" facts in ascending order:

```
print_sorted(N) :-
    findall(path(X), path(X), List),
    msort(List, SortedList),
    print1(SortedList, N).
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to elaborate on the pros and cons of each approach. That retractable counter, for example, I'm really curious to hear the conditions which it would be the suggested approach upon.

Comment: I would like to know how to display the output but by ascending order.I know that SQL has order by functions but not prolog.Please advise.

Comment: @Alvin: in this case use print_sorted(3) that I added to my answer. This works in SWI Prolog. Otherwise use the sorting method of your Prolog system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, that there are at least 3 facts and you don't mind if all Solutions are created:

```
three_results(A,B,C) :- findall(X,path(X),[A,B,C|_]).
```

You can also use something like:

```
n_results(0,A,A) :- !.
n_results(N,A,R) :- path(X), (member(X,A) -> fail; true), N1 is N - 1, n_results(N1,[X|A],R).
three_results(X) :- n_results(3,[],X).
```